# Creating new voice commands for android auto?

Tags: android-auto

I am going to develop an application for android auto so I have been searching what to do. It seems there is a lot of constraints about this subject.

I need to know if i can create new special voice commands for my application?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, not using the default api that google provides.  You may be able to create a listener using the accessibility service but the Android Auto API are not that advanced to where you can add voice actions.

dave

Answer (score 0):

Dave is correct, you are currently limited to the API endpoints that are in the Auto documentation.

But... you could work around it by declaring a media service, listening for the callback from the library, and simply taking the 'search term' of a song/media item and rerouting that term to a switch statement of different custom commands...

It's hacky, but should work...